# Postgresql add double quote to string while COPY-TO

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm writting a file from a DB-Procedure.
I need to export a string value and I have to add double quotes in front and back of the string.
exp: "TEST".

I use the following code but the result is always like """TEST""" and I don't know why.

```
EXECUTE 'COPY (
                SELECT concat(''"'', x.text1, ''"'')
                    FROM my_table x            
                ) to ''' || dump_path || ''' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '','', ENCODING ''WIN1252'')';
```

Comment: It is escaping the double-quotes because of the CSV format.  What happens if you specify `FORMAT text`?

Comment: Yes, try `(FORMAT 'text', DELIMITER ',')`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek woked perfectly thank you!